# Auto-stretching table-cell div css

Tags: html, css

I know there is a lot of similair questions but none of them helped me to solve this. I have very simple setup:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.dontBreakmyLine {
  display: table-cell;
}

.iCanUseWhatIsLeft {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dontBreakmyLine">
    Some generated text
  </div>
  <div class="iCanUseWhatIsLeft">
    Another generated text
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to stretch first div to content and let the another one take remaining space. I know that maximum width of generated text in first div will be 300px, but max-width dont work here as I would like. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Float the first one to the left …?

Comment: Seconded. This is not what tables are for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but if you're okay with the line not breaking you can set the left cell to a small width and set the text not to break on whitespaces

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hqWaU/

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.dontBreakmyLine {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.iCanUseWhatIsLeft {
    display: table-cell;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that the two child elements will remain on a single line, not necessarily the case for floats or inline-blocks.

Comment: This solution is great, I completely forgot about 'white-space:nowrap;'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution without `display: table;` would be to set both boxes to `position: relative;`, float the left and stretch the right one with `right: 0px;` ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uZMny/1/)).

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

.dontBreakmyLine {
    max-width: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.iCanUseWhatIsLeft {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The text will break as soon as it's longer than `300px` but If it won't be longer it doesn't matter. Add `display: table-cell` back to the boxes if you don't want the right text flow under the left text.

If you still wan't to prevent the line-break you can use `white-space:nowrap;` maybe even in combination with `overflow: hidden;` ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uZMny/2/)).