# set button width to 100% of parent div without a line break

Tags: html, css

I have a div called text, and next to it I want a button which should take up the remaining width of the screen so I set the width of the button to 100%, but it takes that as 100% of the screen and appears below the text div. How can I make it so the button is 100% the width of its parent div and not the whole screen so it all appears on the same line, without setting a width for the text div? Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1amvwzuw/). Thank you.

**css**

```
#text{
      float:left;  
}

div{
    border:1px solid red;    
}

button{
       width:100%;   
}
```

**html**

```
<div id = "text">text</div>
<div>
   <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using `display: table-cell` css:

Try something like this:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/1amvwzuw/4/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell" id="text">text</div>
    <div class="cell">
        <button>button</button>
    </div>
</div>

div.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

div.cell {
    border:1px solid red;  
    display: table-cell;
}

button {
    width:100%;   
}

/* use this style to set width of the #text cell to exactly the width of it's cotnents */
#text {
    width:1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: a good solution, but it leaves quite a gap between the text and the button. +1

Comment: @user2014429 – take a look at the edited answer above: it will size the `#text` cell to exactly fit it's contents (the [jsfiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/1amvwzuw/4/) has been updated as well)

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you run into any issues with it.

Comment: just implemented it, Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can place them in a div together and display them as flex.

http://jsfiddle.net/1amvwzuw/2/

```
<div class="flex">
    <div id="text">text</div>
    <button>button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your parent container a width. So text could be like, 80% then the div that contains `button` could be 20%. then button will be 100% of the parent div and both divs will be beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

So `div` element is a block element. That means it will start on a new line and the next element after it will be on a new line as well. What you can do here is to set `display: inline-block` to both `divs` you have.

If you don't need a block element just use an inline one like `span`

http://jsfiddle.net/1amvwzuw/3/

Answer (score 0):

If your browser-matrix allows it this is the perfekt opportunity to try out flexbox:

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="text">text</div>
    <div class="button-wrapper"><button>button</button></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
}
.button-wrapper{
    flex: 1;  
}
button {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1amvwzuw/5/

if not look at this question to see how to stretch a div using display:table-cell:
[Auto-stretching table-cell div css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320431/auto-stretching-table-cell-div-css)